# Not finding any solution for "Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1"

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, cloud

I am new at GCP and I want to create a Windows Server VM (2 vCPU with 4GB Memory) on region **asia-south1(Mumbai)**. While creating it always shows

> Quota 'CPUS' exceeded. Limit: 0.0 in region asia-south1.

[image: error_cpus_exceeded]

As per some suggestions I went to raise request to increase CPU quota. But I saw the region already have limit 8.

[image: increase cpu limit pic]

Still I resubmitted that request with the same limit. How can I solve this?

Comment: We cannot help you. Only Google can change your quotas. My recommendation is to use a different region such as `us-central1` where you might have (or be approved for) quota.

Answer (score 1):

You can [request an increase in quota](https://cloud.google.com/compute/quotas#requesting_additional_quota) or, as @JohnHanley mentioned, use a different region.

There is also a [ServerFault thread](https://serverfault.com/questions/1044104/getting-quota-cpus-exceeded-limit-0-0-in-region-asia-south1-error-while-ad) about the same quota for `asia-south1`.